# How to get FQL-data, and post it to my own database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, facebook-fql

We've made a facebook fql query to get a list of friends with the 'Online' or 'idle' presence. Now we want to get the data from the fql-database to another program, like a local database. I've tried to program a table, something like a fql query in a sql query but it doesnt work. Later we want to try to program an app in Java or Php or etc to get and analyze the data as a school project.

Is there a way to connect to the facebook-database and receive data with the help of SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the result of the FQL query and then format it into a MySQL Insert Statement to add it to your own database. You won't be able to just drop in the FQL result and expect it to work.

Something like:

```
$friends = $facebook->api( /* FQL query to FB */ );

foreach ( $friends['data'] as $friend ) {
  mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO Friends (id, name, status) VALUES ( '".$friend['id']."', '".$friend['name']."', '".$friend['status'])."' )" );
}
```